Users with more than 1,000,000 reputation make scrollbars in UI
On Linux, superfluous scrollbars may be visible in the UI at:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/
I imagine we didn't have any 1M+ rep users when the stylesheets for this page were last touched - probably just a minor css tweak is needed to make them go away.
Chrome browser on Linux (RHEL 8.6).


imagine using system fonts

This seems to be a problem on the user's end. I can't repro this on any browser (Windows)

@Cerbrus different text rendering across OSes is expected and by-design behavior.

No Repro on FF v127 (Win10) with SO Wider Screen Userscript both enabled + disabled (and logged in), but Repro on CrEdge v126 (not logged in, and no Userscripts installed).

Seeing as I only access SO from one device, I never knew... It seems that was a(nother) very popular design choice, looking at the answers cough cough.

Why is the question closed as can no longer be reproduced? It is reproducible.

@wim I can't reproduce it on macOS (tested Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) so based on Ryan's answer it's presumably an OS-specific issue, and maybe the people who voted to close didn't notice that part. Might be worth editing to clarify?

@JohnMontgomery The thing that the close voters didn't read was the close reason they were selecting, which clearly says "Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete." Neither of those apply.

Hum, strange, following on my previous Comment from 6 days ago, no Repro anymore on CrEdge (not logged in), and still at v126. // But "double-Repro" (=double Scrollbar, Horizontal + Vertical) on ['Profile' > 'Activity' > 'All actions'] for the Inbox Navbar, on all Tabs with content + double Timestamp scrambled, but that's a different issue, that sbd will probably report "at some point"... (This one on FF127, logged in of course, with oodles of Userscripts and custom 'Ad-Block' Scripts that could play a role, I didn't test with all of them disabled... But happens only on 'All actions'.)

Speculation: this CSS isn't using Stacks and thus is getting an outdated set of fonts that is not reflective of the intended font selections (see Update 3 here).
This element on stackexchange.com has a resolved font-family value of:
system-ui, -apple-system, "system-ui", "Segoe UI", Ubuntu, Roboto, "Noto Sans", "Droid Sans", sans-serif

Contrast this with, say, some sans-serif text on Meta Stack Overflow:
-apple-system, "system-ui", "Segoe UI Adjusted", "Segoe UI", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif

Note that the stackexchange.com one has Ubuntu in the list, but not Liberation Sans, a switch made in the aforementioned update 3 to the fonts.  I suspect they forgot to also change it in the non-Stacks CSS used by stackexchange.com

Is there something I can check in my browser for you to confirm speculation?

@wim if you edit the font-family value for .statsBox .number using your browser's developer tools to the second value in my answer, does that fix the issue?

The value was system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Ubuntu","Roboto","Noto Sans","Droid Sans",sans-serif. Removing system-ui, from the value fixed the issue.
